# pyspark join fails when (Azure) databricks runtime version changes

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a databricks notebook and in one of the cells, there are many joins.

pseudo code:

```
df_final = df_final.join(dfTest1, on ['ID], how = 'left').drop(dfTest1.ID) \
                   .join(dfTest2, on ['ID], how = 'left').drop(dfTest2.ID) \
                   .join(dfTest3, on ['ID], how = 'left').drop(dfTest3.ID)
```

The same command runs successfully with 6.6ML (includes Spark 2.4.5, scala 2.11) but fails with run time version 7.3 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, scala 2.12)

Any one faced this issue? How to overcome this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by fail? What error did you get?

Comment: It fails on line 3 saying "ID" can not be resolved

Comment: could you please post a minimal code that reproduces this error, from what you've shown here I don't see why this happens

Comment: Thanks @mck. When I removed .drop(dfTest*.ID) from all the 3 lines, error disappeared.  Looks like this is an issue with run time version. WIth the earlier version, no error was shown. Also we don't have to drop the column on which join is happening between two pyspark dataframes. That was a bug.

Comment: It might be an issue with your data, seems like `ID` doesn't exist in the 3rd df.